# Firebase cloud function Admin SDK - listing user - problem with pagination

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I've implemented a HTTP callable function to get all users. As you see in my code, the problem is that `requestedPageToken` (from client call) is the same as `listUsersResult.pageToken` (returned from `listusers` function). My client app calls this function with the same token over and over again but it gets only the first page of users because `listUsersResult` returns the same token and not the next page token. Here is my TypeScript code:

```
export const listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    try {
      if (data !== null) {
        const requestedPageToken = data.text;
        console.log("PageToken is: " + data);
        return admin.auth().listUsers(50, requestedPageToken)
            .then((listUsersResult) => {
              console.log("New PageToken is: " + listUsersResult.pageToken);
              return listUsersResult;
            }).catch((reason) => {
              return Promise.reject(
                  new Error(reason));
            });
      } else {
        return admin.auth().listUsers(50);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error: " + error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

I could not find where the problem is. Why am I not getting the token for next 50 users?

Comment: Is your log message correctly printing?

Comment: Yes, here is the output from logs of these two log messages:
`PageToken is: 2Sq0O25MHMgXdcQMz5M0...` and here is the other one
`New PageToken is: 2Sq0O25MHMgXdcQMz5M0...`

Comment: Sweet, so the problem was exactly what I thought it was: `data` is a string, `data.text` will return `undefined` (because strings don't have a text property), which means that you effectively call `admin.auth().listUsers(50, undefined)` which is the same as `admin.auth().listUsers(50)` - so no token, same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works now. I've made a mistake. Below line:

```
const requestedPageToken = data.text;
```

should be:

```
const requestedPageToken = data;
```

I'm not sure how this change affects what the function returned but none the less it works now.